# Acceder a una variable dentro de una promise

Tags: javascript

Tengo esta promise:

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');

let ip 

(async function miIp(){
     return res = await publicIp.v4()
})().then(res => {
    ip = res
})

console.log(ip)
```

Me sale undefined por el scope, pero ¿como hago para sacar esa ip fuera del promise?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes una confusión al momento de usar async, await y then.

Tu código podría verse de esta manera con [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```javascript
let ip = null;
(async ()=> {
    ip = await publicIp.v4();
})();
console.log(ip);
```

O de esta otra manera con [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

```javascript
let ip = null;
publicIp.v4().then((res) => {
  ip = res;
});
    
console.log(ip);
```

Comment: El problema que no puedo acceder a la variable dentro del promise

Comment: estas implementando mal la promesa idelfonso

Answer (score 0):

No es un problema de scope (el console.log está en el mismo scope que la declaración global) sino el hecho de consultar el valor antes que se resuelva la promesa.

La solución cambia dependiendo del uso que quieras darle a IP, pero si fuera un solo gran script, entonces podrías meter todo en el handler donde se resuelve la promesa:

```
publicIp.v4().then(ip=>{
   console.log(ip);
   // todo tu software
     
});
```

Si el valor de IP se utiliza dentro de una función (por ejemplo una ruta de express) entonces es más limpio hacer que la función en el scope inmediatamente superior sea asíncrona. Por ejemplo, en vez de

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');

let ip 

(async function miIp(){
     return res = await publicIp.v4()
})().then(res => {
    ip = res
})

app.get('/',(req, res)=> {
  console.log(ip)
});
```

Refactorizarlo a

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');
 

app.get('/',async (req, res)=> {
  let ip = await publicIp.v4();
  console.log(ip)
});
```

Comment: Osea, que no se puede usar las variables internas del promise fuera del mismo

Comment: No es eso, es que afuera no tienes cómo saber si ya se resolvió. Pero si en tu script original envuelves el console.log en un setTimeout, tendrías el valor dependiendo de cuánto hayas esperado. Es frágil.